# Laravel 5.2 Mutate dates

Tags: php, laravel, momentjs, datetimepicker, php-carbon

I've recently implemented a bootstrap-datetimepicker.js which is based on moments.js for some visual effects. Before the datetime widget I simply had an input field with date&time. 
Now I am facing some issues, there is a kind of conflict between Carbon and Monents.js with the datetime format.

This is my inputfield:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Veröffentlichungsdatum') !!}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            {!! Form::input('datetime','published_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control datetimepicker']) !!}
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I save an artcile this exception is thrown:

```
"InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data"
```

Without using the BS datetimepicker my datetime is looking like this:

```
2016-10-07 16:32
```

I am using this in My Model to format it properly:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) {
  $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $date);
}
```

However, with the BS datetimepicker my datetime is looking like this:

10/25/2016 21:35

I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: well you can use createFromFormat for that format, and then do something like `srtpos($date, '-') !== false` to see what format it is in like in an if or such.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done it like this, hope it helps:

```
/**
 * Define how the date attribute gets saved to the database
 * @param $date
 */
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $date)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Note the `->toDateTimeString()`